# How to parse xml with logstash and ignore global tag?

Tags: xml, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using logstash to parse xml in my s3 bucket and send it to my elasticsearch server. All my xml is in a tag

```
<ServiceSales xmlns="dmoes"> 
     <ServiceSalesDetailsClosed>...</ServiceSalesDetailsClosed> 
     <ServiceSalesDetailsClosed>...</ServiceSalesDetailsClosed>
</ServicesSales>
```

I want to ignore the first tag "ServiceSales" , I tried :

use "message.ServiceSales" as source in my xml codec

```
xml {
   source => "message.ServiceSales"
   target => "ro_detail"
}
```

This way I get my xml divise by ServicesSalesDetailsClosed but the event are not parse

ignore and use multiline code

```
codec => multiline {
    pattern => "<ServiceSalesDetailsClosed>"
    negate => "true"
    what => "previous"
}
```

It works except for the first event which is not parse.

Do you know how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar case. For this xml:

```
<ROOT number="34">
    <EVENT name="hey"/>
    <EVENT name="you"/>
</ROOT>
```

I use this logstash configuration:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/path/prueba.xml"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "<ROOT"
      negate => "true"
      what => "previous"
      auto_flush_interval => 1
    }
  }
}
filter {
  xml {
    source => "message"
    target => "xml_content"
  }
  split {
    field => "xml_content[EVENT]"
  }
  mutate {
    add_field => { "number" => "%{xml_content[number]}" }
    add_field => { "name" => "%{xml_content[EVENT][name]}" }
    remove_field => ['xml_content', 'message', 'path']
  }
}
output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

And I get this output:

```
{
        "number" => "34",
    "@timestamp" => 2016-12-23T12:20:35.587Z,
      "@version" => "1",
          "name" => "hey",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "multiline"
    ]
}
{
        "number" => "34",
    "@timestamp" => 2016-12-23T12:20:35.587Z,
      "@version" => "1",
          "name" => "you",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "multiline"
    ]
}
```